# getServerSideProps not working for me as expected

Tags: typescript, next.js, getserversideprops

I am unable to figure out why server-side props not working for me in nextjs (v12)
I am using getServerSideProps insides pages/details/index.tsx

```
export const getServerSideProps = (async (context: any) => {
  const name = context.query.name;
  const response = await fetchDetails(name);
  const data = response.data;
  console.log(data); // this line is printing details in server
  return { props: { data } };
});

export default function Page({data}: {data: any) {
    console.log('p', data);
    return <DetailsForm data={data} name="abc"/>
}
```

While I am able to get props.name as "abc", but data comes as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with how you are destructing the response on client. I tried to replicate your scenario and I was able to read the data both on server and client. Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-bci25a?file=pages%2Fdetails%2Findex.js) Stackblitz repo.